# Count invites in a Discord Message

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Is letting a Discord py bot to count how many Discord Invites in a message possible? I have been searching in the internet for a long time about this and nothing is found.

Comment: Are you asking to see how many invite links are present in a message's content, or whether to count how many times an invite has been used?

Comment: how many invite links are present in a message's content

Answer (score 0):

Using the `re.findall` method, you should check for a regex in the message. For example:

```py
import re

inviteregex = re.compile(r'discord(.gg|.com/invite)/.{3,10}') # Compile the regex...

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
     links = re.findall(inviteregex,message.content) # Find all of the links in the text using the regex
     linkcount = len(links) # Set linkcount to the length of the list 'links'
     # linkcount is now the number of links in the text...
```

EDIT: Fixed the regex, forgot a slash which made .gg invites not be captured fully.

Comment: I have just run a complete test on the above method but it doesn't work

```
import re

inviteregex = re.compile(r'discord(.gg|.com/invite/).{3,10}') # Compile the regex...


links = re.findall(inviteregex, input("link: "))

print(links)
```

I tried this and I input this: discord.gg/gpDcZfF dsgasdhakhsjd

and it give me this: ['.gg']

Comment: That's interesting, the code works perfectly for me. The most I can think of is that the regex is incorrect somewhere.

Comment: yes it can count but not returning the entire link

Comment: Found it- my regex was incorrect. I edited it to `discord(.gg|.com/invite)/.{3,10}`.

Comment: looks like it still cannot work. I have input this `here is the link discord.gg/gpDcZfF`
It still returns me ['.gg']

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, I tested the regex and then sent it here. Here's the tests I did on it: https://regexr.com/5k3b2

Comment: maybe because it is javascript?

Comment: Oh it doesn't mean JS like that... In that menu you choose Javascript or Server: Javascript being process in the browser, server being process remotely. Either way, I've tested this regex in my own code and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

> =[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLAIj.png) Here is the photo which shows that the above method doesn't work somehow